# json.stringify: After resizing of an object height and width properties are not updated

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

Next code create triangles on canvas, if you are not clicking over an existing triangle. And you may save all elements to JSON with clicking on "save" button.Then preview the JSON variable in console.

My problem is that after resizing of an object, height and width are not updated in Json, when clicked on save again.
To resize the triangle You have to click on it. Then grab one of the anchor rectangles and drag it from  the center of triangle.

What action must I perform to have also new height and width of the object?

Next is code snippet on jsFfidle: https://jsfiddle.net/ug7p9myc/76/

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c5');

function some1(x1, y2) {
  var c = new fabric.Triangle({
    left: posX2,
    top: posY2,
    width: 15,
    height: 25,
    strokeWidth: 3,
    fill: '#666',
    stroke: '#666'
  });
  canvas.add(c);
}

var posX2, posY2;
canvas.on('mouse:down', function(e) {
  var pointer = canvas.getPointer(e.e);
  posX2 = pointer.x;
  posY2 = pointer.y;
  if (e.target) {} else {
    some1(posY2, posY2);
  }
});

function saveJsonF() {
  var jsonToPHP = JSON.stringify(canvas.toObject());
  console.log(jsonToPHP);
}
document.getElementById("saveJsonID").onclick = saveJsonF;
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.22/fabric.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" class="Btn1" id="saveJsonID" value="Save" /></br><br>
<canvas id="c5" width="1060" height="550" style="border: 1px solid black"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [getScaledWidth](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html#getScaledWidth) and [getScaledHeight](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html#getScaledHeight) to get the transformed values. If you scale an object, its scaleX and scaleY value changes.

Comment: With this answer  my problem is solved.  But  still I think it was no need to complicate things with introduction of scale as properties

Comment: I mean  in some graphic program for drawing. Once you  scale one object, information of scaling factor is lost. Then you have just new dimension.

Comment: @Sailo1, in fabricjs it doesn't change the original dimension rather changes scaleX and scaleY.